# Angular - This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'void' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)

Tags: angular

In my Angular-11, I have this code:

```
user(){
    const data = localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
    if (data != null && data!='undefined') {
      return data;
    }
    this.api.get('auth/user', this.header).subscribe(
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
      data => { this.dataHandler(data) },
      error => { console.log(error) }
    );
  }
```

But I got this error:

> This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'void' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)

Then this is highlighted:

> if (data != null && data!='undefined') {

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must notice that `localStorage.setItem()` function does not have return value and `const data` assign with `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user)); // sets data as undefined always
    if (data != null && data!='undefined') { // data !='undefined' => undefined != 'undefined' will always return true
      return data;
    }
```